# Applying a shader to framebuffer object to get fisheye affect

Tags: opengl, graphics, glsl

Lets say i have an application ( the details of the application should be irrelevent for solving the problem ). Instead of rendering to the screen, i am somehow able to force the application to render to a framebuffer object instead of rendering to the screen ( messing with glew or intercepting a call in a dll ).

Once the application has rendered its content to the FBO is it possible to apply a shader to the contents of the FB? My knowledge is limited here, so from what i understand at this stage all information about vertices is no longer available and all the necessary tests have been applied, so whats left in the buffer is just pixel data. Is this correct?

If it is possible to apply a shader to the FBO, is is possible to get a fisheye affect? ( like this for example: http://idea.hosting.lv/a/gfx/quakeshots.html )

The technique used in the linke above is to create 6 different viewports and render each viewport to a cubemap face and then apply the texture to a mesh.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A framebuffer object encapsulates several other buffers, specifically those that are implicitly indexed by fragment location. So a single framebuffer object may bundle together a colour buffer, a depth buffer, a stencil buffer and a bunch of others. The individual buffers are known as renderbuffers.

You're right — there's no geometry in there. For the purposes of reading back the scene you get only final fragment values, which if you're highjacking an existing app will probably be a 2d pixel image of the frame and some other things that you don't care about.

If your GPU has render-to-texture support (originally an extension circa OpenGL 1.3 but you'd be hard pressed to find a GPU without it nowadays, even in mobile phones) then you can link a texture as a renderbuffer within a framebuffer. So the rendering code is exactly as it would be normally but ends up writing the results to a texture that you can then use as a source for drawing.

Fragment shaders can programmatically decide which location of a texture map to sample in order to create their output. So you can write a fragment shader that applies a fisheye lens, though you're restricted to the field of view rendered in the original texture, obviously. Which would probably be what you'd get in your Quake example if you had just one of the sides of the cube available rather than six.

In summary: the answer is 'yes' to all of your questions. There's a brief introduction to framebuffer objects [here](http://www.gamedev.net/reference/articles/article2331.asp).

Comment: Ok so after you have created a renderbuffer object, captured the rendered output of the application to be used as a texture, what is the purpose of the fragment shader? You mentioned that the fragment shader can programmatically decide which location to sample. Can you please explain what you meant by this in the context of this problem?

Comment: What you could do is draw a single quad to contain the fish eye lens. Each fragment will get an input (x, y) but instead of just looking up the pixel at (x, y) in the source image and setting that as the output colour, it'll do a calculation to work out where to get the input colour from to make the image look fisheye (probably something like switching to polar coordinates and throwing in a cosine on distance?) — exactly like Photoshop would. Then you're submitting only one quad and getting a pixel perfect fish eye.

Answer (score 2):

Look here for some relevant info:

http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object

The short, simple explanation is that a FBO is the 3D equivalent of a software frame buffer. You have direct access to individual pixels, instead of having to modify a texture and upload it. You can get shaders to point to an FBO. The link above gives an overview of the procedure.